# Flash player, HD videos and games are choppy

Tags: graphics-card, flash-player, high-definition

I have a problem with flash player. HD videos from Youtube or Vimeo and flash games do not play smoothly. I'm using Flash player 11, Windows 7 Sp1, and my graphic card is Intel GMA 4500.

Device Manager shows me that all drivers are installed on my computer, so i don't have any problems with drivers. When I run Google chrome, Resource Monitor shows me 15% ~ 40 % of CPU Usage and 40% used Physical Memory, but when I watch a video on Youtube or play a Flash game, the Resource Monitor shows 70% - 90% CPU Usage.

Also, when I run some HD Video (Frame width : 1920, Frame height : 1080) on my computer, Device Manager shows me 80% ~ 100% of CPU Usage.

before I Reinstall Windows 7, HD Videos and flash games were play smoothly I hadn't any problem with them !!

I hope all this information is enough to answer my question.

Comment: What CPU do you have in your computer?

Comment: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU          900  @ 2.20GHz, ~2.2GHz

Answer (score 2):

Your graphics card [does not support full HD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#GMA_X4500):

> The difference between the GMA X4500 and the GMA X4500HD is that the GMA X4500HD is capable of "full 1080p high-definition video playback, including Blu-ray disc movies",[15][22]

EDIT:

your reinstalled system probably eats more CPU than your previous system did, so you now don't have enough available CPU to do the leftover graphics processing. try running these videos in firefox or IE instead (different plugin, different browser, different CPU overhead). Iḿ just guessing really here; hopefully it's helpful.

Comment: But before I Reinstall Windows 7, HD Videos and flash games were play smoothly I hadn't any problem with HD Videos on youtube and flash games !!

Comment: edit that into your question.

Comment: and when you do, "all this information" is the correct form. :)

Comment: could you be more clear,I can't understand your order

Comment: You edited your question to read "all these informations", when "all this information" is the correct statement. It's really minor - I was just suggesting that you fix that when editing the other in, but it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your CPU (Celeron M 900) is overtaxed relative to the demand of the applications you are running.

That you are needing 70% to 100% CPU when playing a video bears this out. Without enough hardware acceleration provided by the video hardware (the GMA 4500 in your case) the task of decoding the video and displaying it must be borne to a greater extent by the CPU.

Thus, since you can't exceed 100%, any time it would take *more* than 100% to play every video frame, your video skips.

Since your notebook is already a few years old, it's well past the point where you should be thinking about replacing it. In doing so, get as much CPU as you can afford, and video hardware that has support for accelerated video playback.

Comment: so ?? Isn't there any solution for that .. because as I marked I hadn't these problem before i re-install windows 7